# Error to connect mqttData Transport to eclipse broker

Tags: mqtt, kura

I'm trying to publish MQTT messages to the iot.eclipse.org:1883. I installed the heater bundle to Kura 3.0.0. in my raspberry pi B (with raspbian) and set the 'broker-url' in the MqttDataTransport to the Eclipse sandbox broker and the 'connect.auto-on-startup' to true.

I saw that my status did not change after that. Then, I displayed the Kura.log and I realized that DataPublisherService did not connect.[CloudServices disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA7CF.jpg)

`o.e.k.d.h.Heater - Getting CloudClient for heater...
2017-07-21 12:15:20,836 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 7)] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - Activating Heater... Done.
2017-07-21 12:15:21,034 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 7)] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.ConfigurationServiceImpl - Registering ConfigurableComponent - org.eclipse.kura.demo.heater.Heater....
2017-07-21 12:15:21,040 [Component Resolve Thread (Bundle 7)] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.ConfigurationServiceImpl - Registering ConfigurableComponent - org.eclipse.kura.demo.heater.Heater....Done
2017-07-21 12:15:22,974 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - Published to data message: org.eclipse.kura.message.KuraPayload@248966
2017-07-21 12:15:22,986 [DataServiceImpl:Submit] INFO  o.e.k.c.d.DataServiceImpl - DataPublisherService not connected`

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:70)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:650)
... 1 more
MqttDataTransport - xxxxx  Connect failed. Forcing disconnect. xxxxx {}
o.e.k.c.d.t.m.MqttDataTransport - Closing client...
o.e.k.c.d.t.m.MqttDataTransport - Closed
```

`
What must I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's better to copy and paste the actual log rather than an image which is really hard to read and can not be indexed by search engines.

Comment: @hardillb Done. Thanks. :)

Comment: A socket timeout exception means that the machine running this code could not find a route to the iot.eclipse.org machine. This either means iot.eclipse.org was down at the time or your pi is not properly connected to the internet

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for the response. Actually, I am able to ping to iot.eclipse.org and to google.com. So, I guess I have internet access, however, the status in the Cloud Service of Kura is disconnected :(. When I try to connect I get some error: Error connecting org.eclipse.kura.web.shared.GwtKuraException ....

Comment: Could you please provide the exact URL you are using in the Kura configuration? It must be in the form: mqtt://iot.eclipse.org:1883/

Comment: @DavidWoodard I have tried the URL mqtt://iot.eclipse.org:1883/ and the mqtts://iot.eclipse.org:8883/ too. But the kura.log get the error as follows:                                         
org.eclipse.kura.KuraConnectException: "Connection failed. Cannot connect"
 at org.eclipse.kura.core.data.transport.mqtt.MqttDataTransport.connect(MqttDataTransport.java:333)
 at org.eclipse.kura.core.data.DataServiceImpl$1.run(DataServiceImpl.java:501)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ..

Comment: It looks like this may be a network error: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1087670/ . I will update this thread if a solution is found.